# How to set up root password while installing mysql in docker?

Tags: mysql, docker, passwords

I am trying to install mysql in docker and setting default password of root as root using following Dockerfile.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

COPY mysql_setup.sh /software/mysql_setup.sh
RUN sh /software/mysql_setup.sh

CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

Where /software/mysql_setup.sh

```
# Download and Install the Latest Updates for the OS
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

# Set the Server Timezone to CST
echo "America/Chicago" > /etc/timezone
dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata

# Enable Ubuntu Firewall and allow SSH & MySQL Ports
ufw enable
ufw allow 22
ufw allow 3306

# Install essential packages
apt-get -y install zsh htop

# Install MySQL Server in a Non-Interactive mode. Default root password will be "root"
echo "mysql-server mysql-server-8.0.26/root_password password root" | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo "mysql-server mysql-server-8.0.26/root_password_again password root" | sudo debconf-set-selections
apt-get -y install mysql-server


# Run the MySQL Secure Installation wizard
mysql_secure_installation

sed -i 's/127\.0\.0\.1/0\.0\.0\.0/g' /etc/mysql/my.cnf
mysql -uroot -p -e 'USE mysql; UPDATE `user` SET `Host`="%" WHERE `User`="root" AND `Host`="localhost"; DELETE FROM `user` WHERE `Host` != "%" AND `User`="root"; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;'

service mysql restart
```

But above code does not seem to be working as when i enter into docker and use and use root as password it gives an error.

```
root@839f2946bfdf:/# mysql -u root -p 
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
```

How can i fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run a mysql install inside a container in a normal way. Thing like `ufw` cannot be done. The entire `RUN` step is at build time only, so `service mysql restart` won't be running when the container is started, only `CMD` is.

Recommend just using the Docker Library [mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) container. There's a standard `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` variable for setting the root password.